# How can I combine several files into one?

Tags: linux

How can I collect several files into a single file?

I tried GZip, but could only get it to create separate files.

It does not have to be compressed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but the typical format for creating an archive (without compression) containing many files in Linux is [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29). It is then possible to compress the tar file. I believe commands such as gzip are supposed to work on single files and must be combined with tar for multiple files, e.g. .tar.gz would be a compressed (gzipped) tar.

Comment: thats what i want collect all files in one file how to do it by tar?

Comment: @rezx: "Use tar" is an answer to your posed question. To find out how it works, issue `man tar`.

Comment: founded ' tar cvf output_filename.tar /path/to/dir1 ' ^_^

Comment: u may vote to delete the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `cat`:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 > output
```

If you want to combine all files in the current directory:

```
cat * > output
```

If you need to adjust the order of the files in the output, use echo first to get all filenames:

```
echo *
```

Then supply them in the desired order to `cat`.

Comment: not work well, but i try this tar cf x.tar *

Comment: @rezx: Well, `cat` just *combines* the files into a single target (as requested). It doesn't store any information to get the original files back. If you want a file archive, then, yes, `tar` is a much better choice ;)

Comment: cool, but what if i hve 50 files i cant write every file name, cant i use *.* ?

Comment: @rezx: `cat * > output`

Comment: @ oliver, work perfect :)