# Split a file on Windows and join back together on UNIX?

Tags: windows, unix, file-transfer, aix

I have a process that involves transferring files from the Windows LAN to an AIX UNIX server using FTP through a VPN connection.

The problem is that some of the files are very large -- up to 4gb. The VPN is fine with the smaller files, but chokes when the size is increased.

Is there a process I can follow to split a file on Windows XP, send to the server, and join back together on UNIX?

This is for a client, so I don't have the capacity to install anything very large on the Windows machine, and certainly not on the UNIX. Although a business case could be made for this issue, I'd say that would be a last resort.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: can you be more specific about the type of UNIX ? (hp-ux solaris, AIX ?)

Comment: cat should work fine to concatenate the files at the unix box. Also  I found this: http://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows

Comment: @Sibster, it's AIX - see the first sentence ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) allows you to create a zip archive and specify the maximum chunk size of a chunk. 
In windows right click the file `7zip` -> `add to archive...` and chose the split size in the `split to volume` dropdown
And there is a client for windows, and most linux/unix flavors

As an alternative if you have cygwin on the windows side you could use `split -b`[2](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split) on the windows side and `cat`[3](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) on the unix side. just make sure you `cat` the files in the correct order.

Comment: Thank.  This worked well with Dropbox's web brower upload which has a limit of 300MB per file.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the answer is a combination of this: [How to split large file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows)

and this: [How can I combine several files into one?](https://superuser.com/questions/423637/how-can-i-combine-several-files-into-one/423656#423656)

Answer (score 0):

For file split, I use an open source tool sfk from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/files/1-swissfileknife/).
It can be compiled on Windows and all Unix by one command (look for do-compile-unix batch in the zip). Then on first computer, use

```
sfk split 2g bigfile.dat outfile.dat
```

which makes 2 GB parts outfile.dat.part1, .part2 and like. On other computer, use

```
sfk join outfile.dat.part1 fullfile.dat
```

and it will join in correct sequence. Did not try AIX compile so far, but for example ARM embedded.

Comment: Are you associated with this project at all or it's developer?  If so please disclose this per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#promotion) or this might be considered SPAM.

Comment: @KronoS Well, it's open source, so … there's no one making money off it :)